# LocalTime between 23.59 and 00:01

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time, localtime

I want to check if a `LocalTime` is midnight. For this use case midnight is defined as anything in between `23:59` and `00:01`. That is a range of **2 minutes**.

```
private final LocalTime ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 0);
private final LocalTime ONE_MINUTE_AFTER_MIDNIGHT = LocalTime.of(0, 1, 0);
```

I have a method

```
public boolean isAtMidnight(LocalTime time) {
    return time.isAfter(ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT)
        && time.isBefore(ONE_MINUTE_AFTER_MIDNIGHT);
}
```

This method is **always** returning `false`. Even for `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT`. it should, however, return `true`.

How can I check if the time is `+-1` minute from midnight?

Comment: Hint: are you sure you want it to be after 23:59 **and** before 00:01?

Comment: suggestion: the limit variables are more clearly defined as `private final LocalTime ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.minusMinutes(1);` and vide versa

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to check for noon +/- 1 min, you'd need to test for "after 11:59 _and_ before 12:01"...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is 23.59.01 considered midnight?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of checking if `time` is after `23:59` **and** before `00:01`, you should check if it is after `23:59` **or** before `00:01`.

```
public boolean isAtMidnight(LocalTime time){
    return time.isAfter(ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT) || time.isBefore(ONE_MINUTE_AFTER_MIDNIGHT);
}
```

If we look at the implementation for `LocalTime#isAfter`, we see the following:

```
public boolean isAfter(LocalTime other) {
    return compareTo(other) > 0;
}
```

Looking at `LocalTime#compareTo`:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(LocalTime other) {
    int cmp = Integer.compare(hour, other.hour);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = Integer.compare(minute, other.minute);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = Integer.compare(second, other.second);
            if (cmp == 0) {
                cmp = Integer.compare(nano, other.nano);
            }
        }
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

We can see that two instances of `LocalTime` are first compared by their respective hours, then minutes, then seconds, and finally nanoseconds.  For `LocalTime#compareTo` to return a value greater than `0` to satisfy `LocalTime#isAfter`, the hour of the first `LocalTime` instance must be greater than the second instance's.  This is **not** true for `00:00` and `23:59`, hence why your method returns `false`.  The same analysis can be done for `LocalTime#isBefore`, and you'll arrive at the same result.

Keep in mind that you can just check against `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` if you want to be exact, but I assume you're considering any time within a 1-minute range to be "midnight" (including seconds).

Answer (score 18):

The solution is to use `||` instead of `&&`:

```
public boolean isAtMidnight(LocalTime time) {
    return time.isAfter(ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT) || time.isBefore(ONE_MINUTE_AFTER_MIDNIGHT);
}
```

This is so counter-intuitive, isn't it? The trick is that `00:00:01` are not after `23:59`, so that's always going to fail. This is so because `LocalTime.isAfter` or `LocalTime.isBefore` assumes that those are times of **the same day**.

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Comment: This is a much better answer than the highest upvoted one.

Comment: @MrLister I respectfully disagree, mainly because `LocalTime` has no concept of a `day`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do this that way, it cannot fulfil both statements. Consider using or, this code returns true for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LocalTime ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 0);
    LocalTime ONE_MINUTE_AFTER_MIDNIGHT = LocalTime.of(0, 1, 0);
    LocalTime md = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
    System.out.println(md.isBefore(ONE_MINUTE_AFTER_MIDNIGHT) || md.isAfter(ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As already explained, you have to use `||` instead of `&&`. I think is more readable if you reorganize the variables in the condition this way:

```
public boolean isAtMidnight(LocalTime time) {
    return ONE_MINUTE_BEFORE_MIDNIGHT.isBefore(time) || ONE_MINUTE_AFTER_MIDNIGHT.isAfter(time);
}
```

One minute *before* midnight *is before*...